# JavaScript SDK doesn't work properly in facebook app over http protocol

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an application on facebook for example apps.facebook.com/my_app.
My Application is running over https protocol. When it is loaded with secure connection "https://apps.facebook.com/my_app" everything goes fine.

The problem occurs when someone loads my application over http protocol "http://apps.facebook.com/my_app". In this case Facebook JavaScript SDK doesn't work properly.
Particullary. I get the message "Access denied for URL https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3", and the **FB.Canvas.setSize** doesn't work.

I use the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: <? echo $pageheight; ?> });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

The better solution would be if I could update all bookmarks for my app to link to https URL, but facebook doesn't provide such option.

Any suggestion?

By the way it is important for my app to run over https connection, so all requests over http are redirected to https by my server.
I apolgize for my English.